# Change Servlet User Agent

Tags: jsp, mobile, user-agent

I want to show PC users the mobile version of arbitrary websites.  I'm thinking that I want to retrieve the page using a mobile user agent, then pass the page along to the user.

First of all, would that work?

Second, how?  Surely I can't just use `<%@include file="http://...."%>`, because that would just show PC users the PC version of the web site.  I don't think I want to make a custom HTTP client, not if there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reading webpages, that should work.  The user would request the page from you, you'd interecept, change the user agent to mobile, get the webpage, and then return it.  A proxy of sorts.

Unless you perform as a proxy, you might have problems when the user tries to navigate, as the buttons and forms will refer to the site directly, and bypass your user-agent modification.